# How to use ${resp}= Add Time To Time ${Time} ${delay_time}

Tags: robotframework

I am calling the exiting queue time and adding to the delay time using "Add Time To Time".
but getting below mentioned error:

> ValueError: Invalid time string '11:03 AM'.  I want to merge existing time and delay time.

```
${resp}=    Add Time To Time    ${Time}    ${delay_time}
```

I used this code also but not able to convert into and adding

```
${Time}=  Convert Time  ${Time}  result_format=%HH:%MM %P
```

Comment: `${Time}` and `${delay_time}` should be in same time format, [these are the supported time formats](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/DateTime.html#Time%20formats) and i dont see `AM` string in it

Comment: Delay time in minutes only, like 15, 17, .... but how to convert this into time?

Delay time getting  7  (mints)      ----> Define variable    ${delay}      
Existing starting time is  3:04 PM  ----> Define variable  ${Stime}

${resp}=    Add Time To Time    ${Stime}    ${delay}        is it possible?

How to convert delay time ?
or   How to convert Stime?